# Any known instances of friendliness or friendship between opposing dragons?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, dragons

As known dragons are not necessarily enemies of each other despite different alignments.

What I am wondering is are there any known instances of friendliness or friendship between chromatic and metallic dragons?

Comment: I actually meant whether you refer to a particular setting such as Forgotten Realms or Eberron etc or just any setting in general.

Comment: @ThomasE.: Thanks, I figured, just wanted to confirm. Also note that the [dungeons-and-dragons] tag doesn't cover Pathfinder, but if you do want to ask about Pathfinder (1e and 2e) that should probably be its own question anyway since the lore is totally different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not from 5e, the 2000-2002 Dragonlance novel trilogy *The War of Souls* contains an instance of 'friendliness' between Mirror (Solomirathnius), a silver dragon and Razor, a blue dragon. They work together for a while since they have common goals and do not attempt to outright kill each other.

Comment: Is there a particular book in the trilogy that this occurs in, or is it across all the books?

Comment: @V2Blast I don't believe its through all of the trilogy. I read the books a while back from a local library and don't exactly remember across which book(s) it occurs. (I had to do a bit of googling to get the names correct as well).

Answer (score 6):

The [answer by Karan Shishoo](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164351/any-known-instances-of-friendliness-or-friendship-between-opposing-dragons/164363#164363) is probably more in line with what you have asked for, but since you asked for generic lore, let me add the following:

There is **an entire 2e campaign setting** called the *Council of Wryms*, initially published as a boxed set and later as a hardcover book. The setting is located in its own crystal sphere, and the main location is a chain of islands called Io's Blood Isles. The Isles are ruled by a council, with dragon clans of 15 different dragon types (5 chromatic, 5 gem, 5 metallic) represented democratically. Dragons do not war against dragons, and disputes are resolved at the council.